# How to create transparent background from div?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a complete newbie. I have to use a template for a web design class I am taking. I am trying to remove the background color of a div and cannot do so, except when I remove the header PNG I have placed. The background of the PNG is transparent.

This is a link to the template: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1wkxt_QTN4MyWOBZuZlUrGNaafeLNkCsO?usp=sharing

Appreciate any help, thank you!

```css
header {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
    
}

.header {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 

}

.grid-container {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}


.top-bar{
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}

.top-bar-left{
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}

.top-bar-right{
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}

.menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent; 
}

menu {
    background-color: transparent;
    background: transparent;
```

```html
<header class="grid-container">
  <div class="top-bar">
        <div class="top-bar-left">
            <ul class="menu">
            <img src="img/headerimage.png" alt=""/>  
          </ul>
    </div>
        <div class="top-bar-right">
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a></li>
                <li><a href="about.html">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="resources.html">Resources</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Could you check the code as the HTML is not 'legal' - there is a ul element with a child img.

Comment: This was it, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to remove the background color of a DIV element, you could use `rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);`

So your CSS should look like this:

```css
header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
}

.header {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}

.grid-container {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0); 
}
```

Alternatively; you could remove `background` and `background-color` and just use `opacity: 0;`. I hope this helps you out!